# How to add option for share dialog in iOS app?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, share

I want to add a options where to share link in my iOS and Android app like this image[image]

i saw this in FB documentation over there https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share/ but i didn't find the code or way how to this in iOS or android. On the top of the dialog there is a button to choose where to share. In the given image it is on the top of dialog with text `Share on your timeline`
any body have an idea how to do it in iOS and Android?

Comment: ios: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share-dialogs-ios-sdk/, android: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android you send a share intent which facebook can handle it with broadcast/receiver style.

Have a look [Sending Simple Data to Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html)

Thanks for your help.

A question arrises from here.

When we share using share intent, than the post is share on my behalf not on the page behalf for example..

I share a post an it shows in this way on my Test Wildcats facebook page.[image]

I want that it show me that this share is posted on the page Test Willdcats name.[image]

Comment: When we share using share intent, than the post is share on my behalf not on the page behalf.

Comment: Ah I got what are you aiming for.

Comment: So will it make any sense. Can you help me regarding this one

Comment: I've searched a little about that couldn't find anything. And facebook is blocked here so i can't refer to their docs

Comment: Ahhh okkk if you find any way regarding this one than let me know plz